# Remote SQL Server (Ubuntu) Slow Connection on local SSMS (Windows)

Tags: sql-server, docker, ssms, sql-server-2019

I am running SQL server inside my EC2 Ubuntu 22.04 with docker. This is my `docker-compose.yml`. I am running the docker inside 16 GB RAM and 4 vCPU.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: password
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/mssql-data:/var/opt/mssql/data
    restart: always
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '4'  
          memory: 8G
```

**The Problem**

I am able to connect to my DB with SSMS but the query and connection are slow. As I tried from an 8GB RAM Server & 4GB RAM Server. This SQL server works fine at the application level. But when I am connecting it from my local windows SSMS these are very slow. Even the 16GB RAM server takes almost the same time.

**The Solution I Tried**

- Latest SSMS on my PC.
- Network Protocol to TCP/IP 
  [image: Network Protocol to TCP/IP]

  -Increase Docker Resource (Setting nearly a good RAM allocation).

  sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
  GO
  RECONFIGURE;
  GO

  sp_configure 'max server memory', 100000;
  GO
  RECONFIGURE;
  GO

**Still Facing Problem with 16GB RAM & 4vCPU**

My previous SQL server was in 4GB and 8GB RAM server and those were in the US. But I created this instance in Mumbai, Well, I think I am getting a little bit better performance. Like a query took almost 10 sec.

On the other hand, I have a SQL server in Azure. When I tried to connect the SQL server from my local it's performance was way better than my new instance.

How can I fix the remote connection slowness issue?

Comment: Might not be the exact cause of your issue but you're definitely setting your `max server memory` way too high. You've set it to 100GB, and you only have 16GB of ram. SQL is going to try to allocate up to 100GB of memory, and you're going to have issues with that. The general rule of thumb is to set SQL Server's max memory to 75% of the available memory that isn't being consumed by other processes. So with 16GB, you should probably let the server/OS have at least 2GB, Docker needs another 2GB, leaving you with 12GB.  then use 75% of that (i.e. 9GB) as the amount for your SQL Server.

Comment: I'd also recommend doing some basic network troublshooting to determine if it's your actual connection that is slow (high ping, many hops, etc).